API to fetch the 'Activity' of an issue in Jira dc
In short: I am looking for an API or any other method to fetch the details of 'Activity' within a Jira issue.
Detailed description: My application involves creating issue payloads and sending them to Cosmos when a webhook event is triggered. However, we have observed that when issues of types such as test, test plan, or test set (Xray issue types) are imported through the Test Case Importer, the updated timestamp of the Jira issue is not being updated, and no events are triggered.
It would be very helpful if I could obtain the API for 'Activity' in Jira. Additionally, I would appreciate any suggestions on a better approach to handle this scenario effectively.
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
Nothing as I couldnt think of any better way!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
